# Using only ID in product url in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The reason I want to do this is non-English product titles are automatically used in the slug that renders a very long URL with percentage signs, e.g. `/product/%e9%97%bb%e7%a8%bf%e5%8f%91%e5%b8%83/`, which doesn't look good at all, especially when shared as URLs, sometimes inconveniently lengthy.

So it seems much better to use only product ID in the URLs such as `/product/1178/`

Searched around and never found anything relevant. Tried Settings > Permalinks > Product permalinks > Custom base = "/product/%post_id%/" but the slug is still appended as `/product/1178/%e9%97%bb%e7%a8%bf%e5%8f%91%e5%b8%83/`

Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/251759/17200), is it to modify it to be used for WooCommerce products so product IDs are used for slugs when creating the product?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Now the product IDs are the product slugs every time I create new products.

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'wpse251743_set_title', 10, 3 );
function wpse251743_set_title ( $post_id ){
    //This temporarily removes action to prevent infinite loops
    remove_action( 'save_post_product', 'wpse251743_set_title' );
    //update title
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'        => $post_id,
        'post_name' =>  $post_id, //Wordpress would generate the slug based on the post name
    ));
    //redo action
    add_action( 'save_post_product', 'wpse251743_set_title', 10, 3 );
}
```